# JPEG Corrupted file fixing

Tags: data-recovery, jpeg

I had an old, broken hard disk containing a lot of JPEG files.

I took that hard to an information recovery company.

The company was able to extract part of the files well, But there are many others files that look like this...

[image]

Is it possible to repair these files? The file size is the same as before, and it even shows the image information (camera used, resolution....etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the cause.

### Repair of half grey JPEGs

1. The file may be truncated. You can find out by comparing the file size to similar files with same JPEG settings (quality, resolution).
2. The file may have normal size but partially contain zeros. Use a hex editor like HxD to determine
3. There may be invalid JPEG markers inside actual image data. These will cause most decoders to stop decoding from that point on. Demonstration:

[image]

The first two causes can not be solved, The data simply isn't there.

Option 3 can often be solved. Often these invalid markers are result of random bitflips. A JPEG marker looks like 0xFFnn. If nn aren't values for valid recognized [JPEG markers](https://www.disktuna.com/list-of-jpeg-markers/) it will choke the decoder, but they're often just part of a larger area of corrupt data.

To repair such an image, corrupt data needs to be deleted and replaced by dummy data (zeros for example). This will often bring back the data behind the grey or solid color block, but needs to be color corrected. Then the dummy data leaves 'scars' you would need to correct using a photo editor.

I made a tool (not free) that can help with some of the steps, [this video](https://youtu.be/cz6Mr_glmlA) discusses the issue we see in your example. The video also mentions a free tool you can try. But the process has to be repeated for each corrupt file and is quite labor intensive.

[image]

### Result of recovery

If files were incorrectly recovered to start with then usually trying to achieve a better recovery is the way to go.

Of course it then depends what was wrong with the original storage device.

For example:

**Bad sectors**. Usually first step to recover data from a  drive with bad sectors is cloning / imaging the drive. Usual strategy is to skip over bad sectors and only during a last pass put effort into those. Sometimes last pass is skipped, so retrying the last pass is an option.

**Weak head**: It's not uncommon for one drive to be weaker. Of course swapping the head stack for a donor stack requires a clean room and takes time. Some labs may not even attempt this or may not be equipped for it. As a result their disk image will be lower quality than that from a lab that does head stack assembly swaps.

**Logical issue**: It is also possibly purely a logical issue. Labs or data recovery specialists often default to using their favorite tool. It is possible an other tool may get better results.

Point is, it should be determined if and how a recovery may be retried and obtain better results.

### Last resort ..

I have had cases where re-recovery was not an option. It then becomes a matter of per file determining if it contains useful data or not. In this video I discuss possible steps we can take: https://youtu.be/nMpdPEKIPLU

Comment: I checked on HxD, there is some small parts (one or two) contain 0s

Comment: Some zeros are normal. If half the image is missing and half the file is filled with zeros then that's conclusive.

Comment: Not half the image. it is block of consecutive zeros about 10% of the file then normal data then another block of zeros 5% of the file

Comment: That sounds abnormal. Did the recovery lab share what was wrong with the drive? Was it an actual lab / specialist or someone who does it as side job? Do you still have the drive? Does it spin?

Comment: Actually it was RIAD5 12 disk array. There was two hards of them didn't work. Yes it was actual lab, they was able to recover about 50% of the files correctly and the other 50% were as in the question

Comment: @AbdAlrhman Ah. Well, this could very well explain it then.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148315/discussion-between-abd-alrhman-and-joep-van-steen).

Comment: No I am not going to chat, this question is answered. With 2 drives missing you'll get a lousy recovery. If they can get *one* of the two going, do HSA swap or whatever they need to do, you could have 100% recovery.

Answer (score 2):

If the recovery company is not able to restore them it is hard to believe you can. So the only thing you can do is to crop the images above the corrupted part (if there is something interesting for you) and save them in new place.

And next time use rule 3:2:1 - 3 copies, two medias, one copy offside